# Does passing objects as props interfere with componentWillReceiveProps?

Tags: reactjs, state, setstate

My React app needs to keep track of a configuration object with dynamic keys, so I pass it to a component like this:

```
<Component configuration={this.state.configuration}>
```

While this works, when I am in the Component's `componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps)` I cannot discern configuration changes, because `this.props` has already been updated to `nextProps`.

If this isn't a known issue, perhaps it has to do with the way I handle updates to configuration state in the parent?  Here's how I update configuration state:

```
  handleConfigurationChangeForKey(newOption, key) {
    const configObject = this.state.configuration;
    configObject[key] = newOption;
    this.setState({configuration: configObject});
  }
```

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you're updating the config object, you're mutating it: you can't tell the difference between `nextProps.configuration` and `this.props.configuration` because they're the same object.

The way to get around this is to basically clone the original config object, mutate *that*, and then use setState to make configuration point to that new object.

```
handleConfigurationChangeForKey(newOption, key) {
  const nextConfiguration = {
    ...this.state.configuration,
    [key]: newOption
  };
  this.setState({ configuration: nextConfiguration });
}
```

Using only older language features

```
handleConfigurationChangeForKey(newOption, key) {
  var nextConfiguration = {};
  nextConfiguration[key] = newOption;
  nextConfiguration = Object.assign(
    {},
    this.state.configuration,
    nextConfiguration
  );
  this.setState({ configuration: nextConfiguration });
}
```

Comment: Great answer, and thanks for showing me how to use the new spread operator.

Answer (score 5):

> I cannot discern configuration changes, because this.props has already been updated to nextProps.

This is not true. `this.props` will have the current props, `nextProps` the upcoming ones.

The way you set the state could be the problem. Try creating a new configuration object, using `Object.create` or a deep copying function (such as the one provided by `lodash`).

```
const newConfig = Object.create(oldConfig)
# or
const newConfig = _.cloneDeep(oldConfig)

newConfig[key] = newValue
```

This way, the object won't be equal by reference to the old version. If copying brings a performance problem, you can try the `Immutable.js` library for your state objects.